# SQL: nobel prize table on sqlzoo

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL and do some practice on the internet.

I cannot find the answer for the problem 4a and 4b on http://sqlzoo.net/2b.htm
The table's name is nobel and have 3 colums (yr, subject, winner)

The question is:

Show the years in which three prizes were given for Physics.

Show winners who have won more than once.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you expect to learn if we give you the answer?

Comment: @JohnFx Not how to do my job, so what's the problem?

Comment: @JohnFx Why do u think there's solution manuals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for `4a`:

```
SELECT yr
  FROM nobel
 WHERE subject = 'Physics'
 GROUP BY yr
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

And for `4b`:

```
SELECT winner
  FROM nobel
 GROUP BY winner
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```